# Is Git repo used for collaboration usually a bare repository?

Tags: git, repository

Is Git repo used for collaboration usually a bare repository? For example, Git repo created on Github is usually bare.  Are there cases where people create non-bare repository for cloning?

Comment: *"For example, Git repo created on Github is usually bare."* - Is it?

Comment: Yes Git repo on Github is bare.

Comment: You could clone from a non-bare repository, but it can become messy when you push to it. Not recommended.

Comment: GitHub is bare. And GitHub is one of the largest collection of git repositories. So you basically answered your own question: Yes, is usually is bare. In addition, the same goes for BitBucket. Also, various sources (blogs, articles) futher confirm that repos for collaboration should be bare. Are there cases where people create non-bare repositories? Probably. It is uncommon and not recommended, but it is possible. The 'why' of this is mainly based on opinions and is, in my opinion, not very suitable for Stack Overflow.